# Bitcoin Gold Ledger Derivation path

Tags: address, address-generation, ledger-hardware-wallet, bitcoin-gold

What derivation path for creating addresses is used in [Ledger](https://www.ledgerwallet.com/apps) for BTG? Generated address from the device doesn't correspond the address from the path m/44'/0'/0'/0/0 that is shown for BTG in [BIP39](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/) for the first key.

**UPDATE 1**: (to clear up) I had following (test) mnemonic generated from ledger:

*hurry essay possible egg idea outer poverty doctor sense lab guess gate arrow supreme cave grape sunny deposit erode lemon couch wild fantasy equal*

When I derived key using m/44'/0'/0'/0/0 path (that is shown in [BIP39](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/)), I got **GTUDDiUvkFJtL24f3Bq3pGyTwULuyzMSV1** address (same as on the site), but Ledger expected **GX1FXv2PrRSARyctabywsi5X58teAjYFU4**.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the answer: the path is m/44'/156'/0'/0/0, it gave me expected GX1FXv2PrRSARyctabywsi5X58teAjYFU4 address.

Address header should be 38, dumpedPrivateKeyHeader same as in BTC (=128).

For those, who is seeking parameters for different bitcoin-like altcoins: I found many of them in the [Coinomi](https://github.com/Coinomi/coinomi-android/tree/master/core/src/main/java/com/coinomi/core/coins) repository.

**UPDATE1**: As it was mentioned by [@john-doe](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/75435/john-doe), if you want to reproduce the address this way, you should switch to BIP32 tab and enter the path without the last segment (it would be added automatically for generated addresses).

Comment: If anyone needs it, here's the proof of 156: https://github.com/LedgerHQ/ledgerjs/blob/master/packages/currencies/src/coinTypeToIconName.js#L7

Answer (score 1):

Sovan, your path didn't work with my iancoleman.io/bip39 page. Almost exactly as your

> m/44'/156'/0'/0/0

but without the last 2 characters `m/44'/156'/0'/0`; it makes no sense to me but it makes a world of difference. Thanks for your help.

ps.for the noob like me, may I add, pick BIP32 tab under derivation path otherwise you can't enter this data on the page.

Comment: m/44'/156'/0'/0/0 represents the path for the first address (you can see it to the left of the produced address in the list). As the last segment is added by the site, you should enter only m/44'/156'/0'/0 (as you did) to get the resulting m/44'/156'/0'/0/0 path.

Answer (score 0):

The exact key path for BTG is "156'"